# Prototype : difference between using constructor and just object itself

Tags: javascript

I'm studying javascript prototype.

CASE 01 - works!

```
var A = function() {}
A.prototype.hello = function() {
  console.log('hello');
}

var B = function() {}
B.prototype = new A();

var C = function (){}
C.prototype = new B();

var c = new C();
c.hello();
```

CASE 02 - doesn't work!

```
var A = {
  hello : function() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
var B = {}
B.prototype = A;
var C = {}
C.prototype = B;
C.hello();
```

I think I didn't understand the concept of prototype and constructor or how the objects inherit each other. Can anybody explain why CASE 02 doesn't work?

Comment: I'd argue that it [doesn't actually work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B.prototype` is just going to be a key on `B` object since `B.prototype = A` is going to create a key name `prototype` on `B`. Same happens with `C` , it will create a nested key of prototype

```js
var A = {
  hello: function() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
var B = {}
B.prototype = A;
console.log(B)
var C = {}
C.prototype = B;
console.log(C)
C.prototype.prototype.hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not really explain, but for me it's just a question of syntax:

```js
var A = {
  hello : function() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

var X = Object.create(A);
X.hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the point to note is that prototype is a property of function AND not an object. Case 2 does NOT work mainly because of this reason.